# "AngularJS way" to map values for output in a view

Tags: angularjs, dry, angularjs-view

Am seeking advice on a beginner problem with AngularJS:

**My app has lots of cases where the API it's working with gives a value from a list of possible types, I've pulled the value into my model and then I want to map it to something, eg icons for each type.
As I'm likely to be re-using the mapping of a few of these common types quite frequently, what's a good way to do this that is efficient and allows re-use?**

I'm trying to keep it "DRY" and stick to the "Separation of concerns" so the display logic is as separate from the model as possible.

*I know "good" is subjective, but hopefully people get the idea here...*

This seems to me to be a fairly common scenario, but some tangible examples are:

**i.** Working with files, I get the file type and I want to map it so that a specific picture based on the type shows up.  In an app dealing with files, this would likely come up in lots of places.

**ii.** A weather app - would be told the weather type and then wish to display a particular weather icon (again in lots of places throughout the app)

---

I'm fairly new to AngularJS but I've read around the problem a bit but am unsure how best to proceed given the number of possible ways one might solve it - I'm guessing it could be either:

**a.** Make my own filter, so that I can re-use that in various places within the expressions where I put the values from the model

**b.** Make my own directive (not so clear on this, but my understanding is I could make a directive for a specific purpose, eg if I wanted my "type" to represent a something such as a "stars" counter and feeding in a value like 3 causes it to display 3 stars etc etc)

Any advice or recommendations on where I might find good example code?

Many thanks,

Neil

Comment: could you provide a example using plunkr or jsfiddle? I'm not sure I'm following exactly what your after. An example would be very helpful to understand what problem your trying to approach

Comment: Certainly, good suggestion. I'll have to do it tomorrow morning though (it's quite late here!)

Comment: k,np. If you post an example even if it is in jQuery or javaScript I can help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

model to icons/images is fairly simple manner lets say you have a list of files

```
$scope.files=[
    {
        name:"file name",
        type:'pdf'
    },
    {
        name:"file name2",
        type:'doc'
    }
]
```

then lets say you have a list of documents

  {{file.name}}

then youll have a css stating:

```
.icon-file{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:inlie-block;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}

.icon-file.pdf{
    background-image:url('path/to/pdf.png');
 }

.icon-file.doc{
    background-image:url('path/to/doc.png');
 }
```

as a directive, no isolated scope

```
 angularApp.directive('file',function(){
     return {
           restrict:'AE',
           replace:false,
           template:'<i class="icon-file"></i><span></span>',
           link:function(scope,element,attrs){
                  element.find('li').addClass(attrs.type);
                  element.find('span').text(attrs.name);
            }
      }
 })
```

as a directive, with isolated scope

```
 angularApp.directive('file',function(){
     return {
           restrict:'AE',
           replace:false,
           scope:{
                type:"@type",
                name:"@name"
            },
           template:'<i class="icon-file {{type}}"></i><span>{{name}}</span>',

      }
 })
```

directive usage

```
 <file_type name="file_name" type="type"></file_type>
```

Comment: Did you miss a bit of the answer out?  Also, I realise I perhaps wasn't very clear in the question, but this doesn't seem to address the crux of my question: the re-use aspect (although if it's really so simple, maybe I should bite the bullet and use the same solution each time even if it isn't DRY?)

Comment: in this case reusability is a bogus term, if you are planning just to do styling i would recommend this approach since creating a directive might seem an overkill  how ever ill update my answer to provde you with that approach