# Angular directive for icon format file

Tags: angularjs, icons, directive

I want to create an AngularJs directive that will allow me to display a specific icon (from a folder that contains a lot of different icon) for a specific file, for example:

If **myFile** is an Html file we display **icon_html.png**, etc.

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923260/angularjs-way-to-map-values-for-output-in-a-view#) from Dayan Moreno Leon but he uses a CSS stylesheet to display the specific icon, I was searching something more generic.

Any advice or recommendations are welcome :)

**Update, I tried this** :

My directive :

```
myApp.directive("icon", function () {

return {
    template: "<img ng-src='style/icon/files_type_icons_flat/PNG/icon_{{icon}}.png'/>",
    replace: false,
    scope:   true,
    compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
        // this is link function
        return function (scope) {
            scope.icon = tAttrs.icon;
        };            
    }
};
```

});

My view :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in entities" >
    <td>
        <div icon="{{row.extension}}"></div> &nbsp;{{row[col.title]}}.{{row.extension}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Nothing worked :(

Many thanks.

Comment: you can dynamically append image tag in directive. something like this : element.html(""); if(myFile=='html') element.append("<img src='icon_html.png'/>"); if(myFile=='doc') element.append("<img src='icon_doc.png'/>");

Comment: Thanks for this answer Mansi Parekh, but like I said I search something more generic I have more than 20 type file, so I can't type 20 times "if(myFile==...)". I find this solution :  <img ng-src="style/icon/FileTypesIcons/icons/html/{{row.extension}}_icon.png" class="img-responsive"> . It's what I was searching but I want it in a directive.

Comment: Nobody could help me please ? :)